# After phpmailer send code Variations code is not working

Tags: php, ajax, email, smtp, phpmailer

Hi I'm having three four pages
1.config file
2.form file
3.form execute file
4.send php mail file
Every thing is fine if i'm going use phpmmailer, if I'd add phpmailer code then after send mail code , rest code is not working.

> I'm showing 500 Internal Server Error

execute file code:

```
sendCustomerMail($myassigneduser->email, "Customer Status Change", "templatefile.php", $message, $headers, $other);    
$db = new db();
```

send mail file:

```
<?php
//in this code i'm getting error
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$templatepath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/customer/Templates/';
$body = file_get_contents($templatepath.$template_name);
$other['--TEMPLATE_URL--'] = $templatepath;
foreach($other as $k => $v) {
    $body = str_replace($k,$v,$body);
}
$body = wordwrap(trim($body), 70, "\r\n"); 
$body = convert_smart_quotes($body);
$mail = new PHPMailer;                
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = $email_hostname;                
$mail->Username = $email_username;
$mail->Password = $email_password;
$mail->setFrom($from_email, $company_name);
$mail->addReplyTo($from_email, $company_name);
$mail->addAddress($to, '');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML($body);
if (!$mail->send()) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}



//if i'm use simple php mail whole code is working fine
$headers = 'From:'.$from_email.'' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To:'.$from_email.'' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$templatepath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/customer/Templates/';
$body = file_get_contents($templatepath.$template_name);
$other['--TEMPLATE_URL--'] = $templatepath;
foreach($other as $k => $v) {
    $body = str_replace($k,$v,$body);
}
$body = wordwrap(trim($body), 70, "\r\n"); 
$body = convert_smart_quotes($body);
if (mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) { 
    return 1;
}else{ 
    return 0;
} 
?>
```

> **Note: This all code working Through ajax**

Comment: Do some basic PHP debugging, read some docs, look in your web server log which will show you the error.

Comment: Okay thanks i'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    require_once 'db.php';
?>
```